# Why is fbi.com localhost?

Tags: web, localhost

I am very confused, when I enter fbi.com as url, it shows me localhost

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBQyG.png)

Is it possible that it is because of xampp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whomever registered `fbi.com` (their identity is redacted for privacy in [the whois records](https://who.is/whois/fbi.com) but they are, presumably, **not** the US Federal Bureau of Investigation):

> ```
> Registrant Name: REDACTED FOR PRIVACY
> Registrant Organization: REDACTED FOR PRIVACY
> Registrant Street: REDACTED FOR PRIVACY
> ```

simply set the A record for that hostname to the loopback IP in their [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) [configuration](https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=fbi.com&type=&showcommand=on&colorize=on&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=):

> ```
> fbi.com.      499 IN  A   127.0.0.1
> ```

---

It has nothing to do with XAMPP (which doesn't do DNS) or anything about your system.